# mod_rewrite htaccess parent directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I want any request to http://anydomain/users/pete/whatever redirected to http://intranet/users/prp/whatever

I have this currently working (for the most part) with an .htaccess file. `http://whatever/users/pete/somepage` redirects to `http://intranet/users/pete/somepage`. Everything is working fine as far as I can tell, except one case. Requests to `http://whatever/users/pete` without the trailing slash are redirected to `http://intranet/users/pete//var/www/users/pete`.

I have a hunch this is because the request to `/var/www/users/pete` would only have `/var/www/users/.htaccess` rules applied (if they existed). Instead, Apache is trying to be helpful and point `/var/www/users/pete` to `/var/www/users/pete/` and the RewriteBase isn't being applied?

/var/www/users/pete is my development sandbox.

virtual host doc root is /var/www, defined in config file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
#/var/www/users/pete/.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /users/pete
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^intranet [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://intranet/users/pete/$1 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty close. Can you this code instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /users/prp/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^intranet [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://intranet/$1 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: Did not work. I think its because the .htaccess directives are not being applied one directory up. I added a custom header to test this: 'Header set x-test "hi"' /var/www/users/pete/.htaccess and sure enough it does not make it into the response.

Comment: Can you some garbage text on top of this .htaccess and see if it generates 500 internal error for you.

Comment: You're right, I take it back. Garbage at the top of /var/www/users/pete/.htaccess results in a 500